# Use VBA on both 32 bit and 64 bit for Excel 2013

Tags: excel, excel-2013

Have the following code that I am unable to compile, hope someone can point me in the right direction.

My code is used to open the browseFolder, errors on `.hOwner = hWndAccessApp`

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Type BROWSEINFO
        hOwner As LongPtr
        pidlRoot As LongPtr
        pszDisplayName As String
        lpszTitle As String
        ulFlags As Long
        lpfn As LongPtr
        lParam As LongPtr
        iImage As Long
    End Type

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SHBrowseForFolder Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "SHBrowseForFolderA" _
        (lpBrowseInfo As BROWSEINFO) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SHGetPathFromIDList Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "SHGetPathFromIDListA" _
        (ByVal pidl As LongPtr, ByVal pszPath As String) As Boolean
#Else
    Private Type BROWSEINFO
        hOwner As Long
        pidlRoot As Long
        pszDisplayName As String
        lpszTitle As String
        ulFlags As Long
        lpfn As Long
        lParam As Long
        iImage As Long
    End Type

    Private Declare Function SHBrowseForFolder Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "SHBrowseForFolderA" _
        (lpBrowseInfo As BROWSEINFO) As Long
    Private Declare Function SHGetPathFromIDList Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "SHGetPathFromIDListA" _
        (ByVal pidl As Long, ByVal pszPath As String) As Boolean
#End If

Private Const BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS = &H1

Public Function BrowseFolder(Optional szDialogTitle As String) As String
    Dim X As Long, bi As BROWSEINFO, dwIList As Long
    Dim szPath As String, wPos As Integer

    With bi
        .hOwner = hWndAccessApp
        .lpszTitle = szDialogTitle
        .ulFlags = BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS
    End With

    dwIList = SHBrowseForFolder(bi)
    szPath = Space$(512)
    X = SHGetPathFromIDList(ByVal dwIList, ByVal szPath)

    If X Then
        wPos = InStr(szPath, Chr(0))
        BrowseFolder = Left$(szPath, wPos - 1)
    Else
        BrowseFolder = vbNullString
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: hWndAccessApp is not defined anywhere. And if you've got Option Explicit turned on, it's not going to compile.

Comment: thanks that did the trick I hope once I am able to test it on 64 bit system.

Comment: `hWndAccessApp` is in the Access object library not Excel.